# Troubleshooting running a script using Rscript vs R -f vs IDE

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am having trouble running a script three different ways: the script uses a package which in turn uses the 'parallel' package to speed up a computation and it executes within an IDE (Rstudio) without error, but returns the following error if I try and run it using both, Rscript scriptname.R, or, R -f scriptname.R, an option that was listed for troubleshooting a similar problem in an older forum.

```
2: In mclapply(argsList, FUN, mc.preschedule = preschedule, mc.set.seed = set.seed,  :
scheduled cores 1, 3, 4 did not deliver results, all values of the jobs will be affected
```

I am a total beginner with parallel computing and so want to know if it seems plausible that something is unable to be passed to mclapply(), or is passed incorrectly, as a result of how the script is executed?
How does one troubleshoot problems that occur in a package that is calling a function from another package i.e. do I have to look at cloning their repository and adjusting how those parameters are passed?

I have confirmed the attached packages and loaded via namespace are equivalent in all settings.

I have confirmed the error occurs regardless of how many cores are used.

I have confirmed it is not an artifact of my local PC as the same error occurs within a VM.

Comment: Please build a minimal reproducible example, so it can be tested.